# Query, if a heap is executable

Tags: c, windows, memory, heap-memory, executable

Let's say i have a heap handle from a [HeapCreate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or any other heap-related function.

I would like to find out if a given handle currently has HEAP_CREATE_ENABLE_EXECUTE flag set for it.

Currently i see no API, that could do this, since the only relevant function, [HeapQueryInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366703%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does something completely different.

Obviously, all this using visual c.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: The heap `Flags` value is at offset 0x70 in 64-bit Windows 7 and Windows 10. I don't know an API to request it, specifically, but can't you just check after allocating a memory block? Call `VirtualQuery` to check whether `AllocationProtect` is `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` or just `PAGE_READWRITE`.

Comment: You should know whether your heap is executable. If you have a heap and you don't know whether it is executable, assume that it isn't.